Question about step in the proof about composite field of two Galois field extensions.
This is a statement from "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote (see Prop. 14.4.21.(b)).

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be Galois extensions of a field $F$. Then the composite $K_1K_2$ is Galois over $F$. The Galois group is isomorphic to the subgroup $$H = \{(\sigma,\tau) : \sigma|_{K_1 \cap K_2} = \tau|_{K_1\cap K_2} \}$$ of the direct product $\text{Gal}(K_1/F) \times \text{Gal}(K_2/F)$ consisting of the elements whose restriction to the intersection $K_1 \cap K_2$ are equal.

Proof:

If $K_1$ is the splitting field of the separable polynomial $f_1(x)$ and $K_2$ is the splitting field of the separable polynomial $f_2(x)$ then the composite is the splitting field of the squarefree part of the polynomial $f_1(x)f_2(x)$, hence is Galois over $F$. The map $\varphi:\text{Gal}(K_1K_2/F) \to \text{Gal}(K_1/F) \times \text{Gal}(K_2/F)$ defined explicitly as $\sigma \mapsto (\sigma|_{K_1},\sigma|_{K_2})$ is clearly a homomorphism. The kernel consists of the elements $\sigma$ which are trivial on both $K_1$ and $K_2$, hence trivial on the composite, so the map is injective. The image lies in the subgroup $H$, since $$(\sigma|_{K_1})|_{K_1 \cap K_2} = \sigma|_{K_1 \cap K_2} = (\sigma|_{K_2})|_{K_1 \cap K_2}.$$ The order of $H$ can be compute by observing that for every $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K_1/F)$ there are $|\text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2)|$ elements $\tau \in \text{Gal}(K_2/F)$ whose restrictions to $K_1 \cap K_2$ are $\sigma|_{K_1 \cap K_2}$.

I am having trouble with the last sentence in the paragraph above. Why is the number of $\tau \in \text{Gal}(K_2/F)$ such that $\tau|_{K_1 \cap K_2} = \sigma|_{K_1 \cap K_2}$ exactly $|\text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2)|$?
My thinking so far is that for each pair $\tau_1,\tau_2$ that restricts to $\sigma$ on $K_1 \cap K_2$, we have that $\tau_1^{-1} \circ \tau_2:K_2 \to K_2$ is an automorphism of $K_2$ that fixes $K_1 \cap K_2$ (it is the identity on $K_1 \cap K_2$), so $\tau_1^{-1} \circ \tau_2 \in \text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2) \iff \tau_1\text{Gal}(K_1/F) = \tau_2\text{Gal}(K_1/F)$. So it seems like what we end up with is that $\text{res}(\tau_1) = \text{res}(\tau_2) \iff \tau_1\text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2) = \tau_2\text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2)$, i.e. I believe the idea is that the set of such $\tau$ is exactly one coset of $\text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2) \leq \text{Gal}(K_2/F)$, and hence have the same cardinality as $|\text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2)|$.
One footnote perhaps is that we see that if $\zeta \in \tau_i\text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2)$ for some $\tau_i$ that becomes $\sigma$ on $K_1 \cap K_2$ then $\zeta = \tau_i \circ \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon$ that fixes $K_1 \cap K_2$, so that $$\zeta|_{K_1 \cap K_2} = (\tau_i \circ \varepsilon)|_{K_1 \cap K_2} = \tau_i|_{K_1 \cap K_2} = \sigma|_{K_1 \cap K_2}.$$ So this shows that every element in $\tau\text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2)$ is $\sigma|_{K_1 \cap K_2}$ for $\tau$ that becomes $\sigma$ when restricted to $K_1 \cap K_2$.
I don't feel I've formulated this well enough.

Your argument is correct. Essentially, you show that for any $\sigma$ in $\text{Gal}(K_1 \cap K_2 / F)$, $\tau \in \text{Gal}(K_2/F)$ restricts to $\sigma$ iff it belongs to $\tilde{\sigma} \text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2)$, where $\tilde{\sigma}$ is any extension of $\sigma$ to $K_2$. This is a coset of $\text{Gal}(K_2/K_1 \cap K_2)$ inside $\text{Gal}(K_2/F)$ (which doesn't depend on the choice of $\tilde{\sigma}$), so we conclude as you said.
